# Outlook vs. Gmail inbox Tug-of-War

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, inbox

I'm an Outlook novice, using Win 10, and Outlook with Gmail:

- One IMAP account with POP disabled and Auto-Expunge enabled
- One filter that came with Outlook: *Clear categories on mail*

Outlook shows two inboxes, Outlook's default `Personal` folders and one that's the name of the Gmail account:

- Which Outlook inbox should get new Gmail messages?
- Without using a filter, is there a setting to direct Outlook to use the inbox I choose? 
   If I use a filter, what's the best way to design it?
- Is it normal for sent messages to appear in both Personal Sent and Gmail Sent folders?

[image: Outlook's mailbox structure]

Comment: This used to be handled by a Google Outlook Connector plugin but Google discounted that many many moons ago.  It basically made Outlook understand Google tags.  What you experienced isn't totally unexpected (google tags are not folders)

Comment: Are you using Outlook with a second email account or just a Gmail? The Outlook `.pst` database file is only for exchange addresses that are non-webmail addresses _(webmail providers such as: `outlook.com`| `hotmail.com`|`gmail.com`|etc. and webmail accounts can only use `.ost` database files - `.pst` databases can be out of sync with their server, `.ost` databases cannot and mirror their server)_. (1) `Gmail`:`Inbox` will receive Gmail emails (2) You cannot use the `Outlook`:`Inbox` for receiving/sending webmail emails; (3) Sounds like an Outlook mail rule has been configured to copy sent mail

Comment: Using with one Gmail account. But you answered one of the questions: I can't use Outlook Inbox for receiving Gmail messages -- unless I filter them into that specific outlook folder.

Comment: The distinction is not made by "webmail". The difference is in whether you're using POP vs IMAP (or Exchange sync) – Outlook will happily fetch messages via POP into a .pst file from any account that offers POP access, including Gmail.

Comment: Using IMAP so can have access on phone, tablet, and notebook.

Comment: @user1686 No up-to-date email server uses POP by default - it's generally IMAP or Exchange _(a user may be able to enable POP on a webmail account, but it's a horrendous form of mail delivery that's inefficient, especially w/ regards to mail organization, and why it was abandoned by most providers for IMAP or Exchange)_. I contemplated using IMAP in lieu of Webmail, except Microsoft uses Exchange for their webmail services, but it shouldn't be set up as an Exchange account in Outlook  _(you can,however only reason to do so is to have a `.pst` vs `.ost`, but you don't get the `.pst` benefits)_

Answer (score 1):

> Question: Which Outlook inbox should get new Gmail messages?

Messages received by an IMAP account should always show up
under that account's dedicated inbox.

> Question: Without using a filter, is there a setting to direct Outlook to use the inbox I choose?

No, because it's not Outlook which stores messages in that inbox. As you're using an IMAP account, Outlook only gives you a direct view into the folders and messages that exist in Gmail – it doesn't actually *collect* mail from there like a POP client would.

If you used a filter to move messages from Gmail's inbox to a local Outlook inbox, 1) they would *actually* be removed from Gmail's inbox, affecting the website as well, 2) you'd be basically reinventing POP clumsily. If an independent local copy of all messages is what you want, it might be more appropriate to just use Gmail through POP.

> Question: Is it normal for sent messages to appear in both Personal Sent and Gmail Sent folders?

Yes, the first copy in "Personal" is stored by Outlook before sending, while the second copy is stored by Gmail itself when the message is actually being sent.

This is specific to Gmail – as far as I know, most other mail servers do not automatically store sent messages this way, relying entirely on the client (e.g. Outlook) to do so. Which is why Outlook does it by default.

You can disable the former (in Outlook's account settings) but not the latter.

Comment: 2nd & 3rd sections' wording is factually inaccurate: [2nd] Outlook stores all mail from accounts it's configured with within `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Outlook` ; Exchange-based accounts receive a `*.pst` database, webmail accounts receive an `*.ost` database _(`.pst` databases can be out of sync with their server, `.ost` databases cannot & mirror their server)_. A mail rule can be set to copy mail from a `.ost`-based account to the Outlook `.pst` data file. [3rd]: `.ost`-based account sent mail does not go through the Outlook `.pst` database - it would have to be copied there via a mail rule

Comment: Good advice: I'll let Gmail messages land in its own inbox. I'll disable the Send copy in Settings.

Comment: Agree. Also for myself, in order to avoid any confusion caused by duplicate folders, I usually work with gmail in Outlook and set the "Root folder path" to [Gmail], so that the folder list could be more clear.

Comment: @user1686 Once the factually inaccurate information mentioned above is addressed, I'll change my downvote to an upvote

Comment: @SteveB,if you don't have any questions aboout it, it's recommended to mark the helpful post.

Comment: @Jade, I would, and I would vote, but I've spent time trying to figure out how to do it w/no success. .